# Google fonts triggering "Unsafe script" in chrome

Tags: http, fonts, https, unsafe

When I am using Google Fonts in an HTTPS page it is treated like an "unsafe script" in chrome.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, I needed to use the `<link>` tag and use `https` in it.